# Access application id of a system managed identity in Azure in C#

Tags: c#, azure, azure-managed-identity, azure-service-principal

currently, we are developing an Azure app service application, which has a system managed identity assigned during setup of the app service. We use the managed identitiy with RBAC to access other Azure resources and that is working fine.

Now I want to get some information from the underlying managed identity to perform some checks. Especially I want to read the application id, which is assigned to this managed identity. I want to do that in C#. How can I access this information?

Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Stati

Comment: Are you using ARM for deployment?

Comment: do you want to read it from within the app itself?

Comment: Yes, I want to read it inside the app.  The main reason is that I want to read the application id from within the running app server, encrypt it via public key and send it to a global validation service, which does not run inside the same AD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential();
    string[] scopes = new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
    var token = await credential.GetTokenAsync(new Azure.Core.TokenRequestContext(scopes));

    var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
    var jsonToken = handler.ReadToken(token.Token) as JwtSecurityToken;
    var appid = jsonToken.Claims.First(c => c.Type == "appid").Value;
    Console.WriteLine(appid);
```

Comment: Bowman Zhus answer solved my requirement. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Stati Can you [accept my answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1fqQ.png) to end this question?:)